# Spring JavaMailSender, Tomcat, JNDI

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-mail, jndi

I've been banging my head on this issue, and I'm tired of the squishy sound.

I need to configure a JavaMail instance on a Tomcat platform. Of course, I do not want to hard-code the connection parameters within the war file, so I've been attempting to establish a JNDI configuration. However, I am receiving an exception suggesting that there is a classpath issue (Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator). Here is my code:

```
    <Resource name="mail/Session"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.mail.Session"
          username="jpulcifer@gmail.com"
          password="Camp1onelcap"
          mail.debug="true"
          mail.user="jpulcifer@gmail.com"
          mail.password="Camp1onelcap"
          mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
          mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
          mail.smtp.auth="false"
          mail.smtp.port="465"
          mail.smtp.starttls.enable="false"/>

        Session mailSession = null;

    try {
        mailSession = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/mail/Session");
```

I'm not sure what to do. I've read some comments around to copy mail.jar and activation.jar to [TOMCAT_HOME]/lib, but that seems... awkward. Plus, I'm not sure how to do this in development environment (Eclipse). Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm really stuck here; it doesn't seem like a difficult thing to do, but clearly I'm proving that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not putting mail.jar in Tomcat's lib directory, where **are** you putting it?  You should be able to put it in the [WEB-INF/lib directory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#tomcatconfig).

Comment: It's in the war file. It's a maven dependency that is resolved in the Eclipse classpath.

Comment: Are you sure the maven dependency is actually resulting in it being put in the war file, and not just being used at compile time?  Are you depending on Maven or Eclipse to deploy the war file?  If you extract the war file and deploy it by hand, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the resource, you are asking the server for this resource, in this case a connection to a mail server. It is the server who provides the resource, so the jars should be in the classpath of the server and not of the web application (which uses a separate classloader).

So the javax.mail.jar should be in the TOMCAT-HOME/lib.